# Laravel echo listen readed message

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, echo

How I can listen, if message seen by user?

I have code:

```js
    watch: {
    message() {
        Echo.private('chat')
            .whisper('typing', {
                name: this.message
            });
    }
},
methods: {
    send(){
        if(this.message.length != 0 && this.message.length <= 4000) {
            this.chat.message.push(this.message);
            this.chat.user.push('you');
            this.chat.time.push(this.getTime());
            axios.post('/sendMessage', {
                message: this.message,
                //lastName: 'Flintstone'
              })
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.message = '';
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
    },
    getTime() {
        let time = new Date();
        return time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes();
    }
},

mounted() {
    Echo.private('chat')
        .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
            this.chat.message.push(e.message);
            this.chat.user.push(e.user);
            this.chat.time.push(this.getTime());
            console.log(e);
        })
        .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
            if(e.name != '')
                this.typing = 'typing..';
            else
                this.typing = null;
        });
}
```

I updated:

```js
 methods: {
        seenMessage() {
            axios.post('/setMessagesSeen/' + this.convId)
            .then( response => { this.chat.seen = ''; }) 
            .catch( response => { console.log(response) } )
        },
        send(){
            if(this.message.length != 0 && this.message.length <= 4000) {
                this.chat.message.push(this.message);
                this.chat.user.push(this.user);
                this.chat.time.push(this.getTime());
                this.chat.seen.push('unread');
                axios.post('/sendMessage/' + this.convId, {
                    message: this.message,
                  })
                  .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.message = '';
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
            }
        },
        getTime() {
            let time = new Date();
            return time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes();
        }
    },
```

How I can send class "unread" to element div other user? I can paste class on current user, and I get color on element chat only for me, but how I can hide element for me and other user, when message is seen?

---

I can watch, if message typing. But How I can listen if message seen by user? I need do actions, if message sended for seen message or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if user clicked to textarea, try this :

- First, create a method hasSeen in your Vuejs Instance.

  ```
   ...,
   methods : {
     send :  () => {...},
     getTime:  () => {...},
     hasSeen: () => { 
              axios.put('your-api-or-backend-domains/setHasSeenMessage')
                   .then( response => { //Okay })
                   .catch(response => { console.log(response)})
             }
    }
  ```

  - Then, in your textarea just add onclickEvent:

  `<textarea> name="message" @click="hasSeen"></textarea>`

Comment: Ok but how I can paste example class "unread" to other user if message not seen?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: Instead of changing the question you should create another question for it, otherwise if other users read this question they will not understand the answers!

Comment: Create a github repository and you tell me I will come and look at your code

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873074/remove-class-for-another-user-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things like **facebook** I found a logic here : https://www.quora.com/How-does-Facebook-know-if-a-chat-message-is-seen

- Case 1: The Facebook tab is in focus but the chat-reply text field is not.

It sends out a "seen" notification (ajaxRequest) when you click on the field to type, using the focus event listener associated with the text-field.

- Case 2: The Facebook tab is not in focus
- In case you already had the text box in focus, but were on a different tab, the notification(AjaxRequest) is sent when you switch to the facebook tab. The JavaScript Window Focus and Window Blur events can be used to detect if the tab is in focus. These and the onfocus event for the textbox can be used to send out the notification(AjaxRequest).

So you can create a javascript script that can implement this logic!

I hope it helped you!

Comment: I have function in php, which  mark message as seen. I need send ajax request? When user clicked on textarea?

Comment: If a user clicked on textarea you just send an axios request and set seen field to true in your db

Comment: Ok but How I can listen this on other user?