# Check if other user has seen the message in laravel websockets

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I am using https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets, how can I check if other user has seen the message or not.

```
$('.channels').each(function (i) {
var channel = $(this).val();
console.log(channel, 'channel')
window.Echo.private("message." + channel)
    .listen('MessagesEvent', (e) => {
        $('#chat').append(e.view)
    });
window.Echo.join("message." + channel)
    .joining(user => {
        $(".status").css('background-color', '#00B3FF')
    })
    .leaving(user => {
        console.log(user, 'leaving');
        $(".status").css('background-color', 'grey')
    })
})
```

Comment: Maybe this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/q/48871416/3356380

Comment: @Luigel so it will only consider as seen on textarea click? There is no other way?